# How to use the source command with the system() function?

Tags: bash, perl, system

I need to source a few environment variables in another file. If I use the `source` command with `system()` function, it's complaining about "No such file or directory". Am I missing something?

My code looks like below. In my code, I have only the `system()` function running the `source` command. The source file has just only one command: `pwd` (Present working directory).

**perl_system.pl**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
system "source env.mk"
```

**env.mk** (contents of env.mk which I want to source has just pwd for now"

```sh
pwd
```

When I run this command, I see the below error

```
$ perl -w perl_system.pl
Can't exec "source": No such file or directory at perl_system.pl line 2.
```

Answer (score 4):

source is a shell built-in that executes a shell script using the current shell interpreter.  So it doesn't work as an external command and won't change the environment of your perl process even if you change your system call to invoke a shell instead of it trying to run an external program directly.

You could run your `env.mk` and then output the resulting environment and update perl's environment accordingly, though:

```
for my $env (`bash -c 'source env.mk;env'`) {
    chomp $env;
    my ($var,$val) = split /=/, $env, 2;
    $ENV{$var} = $val;
}
```

(with obvious problems if environment variables contain newlines).

Update: just read *all* of your question, not just the beginning.  If all you want to do is execute a shell script, just do:

```
system "sh env.mk";
```

source is completely unnecessary for this.

Comment: It could be worth noting that `system` uses `sh` shell, and in the `sh` shell there is no `source` command.. therefore the error message

Comment: @HåkonHægland while that's true, system called like that doesn't even use sh; it is perl trying and failing to find the source executable

Comment: I see.. the reason that a call to `sh` is omitted is that there is no shell meta characters in the argument. Thanks.